# Can Rad Studio XE6 be installed with Delphi 2005?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

My PC currently has Delphi 2005 installed. Can Rad Studio XE6 be installed on this same PC without issue? Or, is it a case of one of the other?

Comment: Yes it can. You can install all versions side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, each installation is completely independent of the other. The only caveat is that the file associations will only go to one version -- which will be the latest one unless you disable setting them when you do the install.

Comment: Or install them in any order and use a repair install to get the extensions set for a specific version

Comment: Another caveat is the Just-in-Time debugger, since there can only be 1 JIT debugger active at a time.